# Néron-Ogg-Shafarevich and good ordinary / supersingular reduction

Tags: elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Let $\ell\neq p$ be primes. An elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}_p$ has good reduction if and only if $T_{\ell}(E)$ is unramified.

Is there a more refined criterion on $T_{\ell}(E)$ which tells us whether $E/\mathbb{Q}_p$ has good ordinary or supersingular reduction?

Comment: If $T_l(E)$ is unramified at $p$ you can compute the characteristic polynomial $X^2 - a_p X + p$ of Frobenius at $p$, from which you can determine $a_p$ which gives you your answer. Note that by the Hasse bounds $a_p$ is a small(ish) integer, so you can compute it by computing it mod $l^n$ for $l^n > 4 \sqrt{p}$.